# equal height columns

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used following JS code to create equal height columns:

```
var colHeight = Math.max($('.3columngallery .col1').height(), $('.3columngallery .col2').height(), $('.3columngallery .col3').height());
$('.3columngallery .gallery').height(colHeight);
```

It's working fine in firefox and safari but not in chrome and opera.

Here's the link of the page, where i used this script: http://www.jaspreetkaur.com/gwstudio/product-gallery

Comment: When you say _"not working"_ , What do you mean?

Comment: I don't think the problem is with height, I see they have the same height in chrome too. It might be a problem with floating elements.

Comment: Looks like i need to find a way to call the script when images are loaded. Currently i am using $(function() { ... });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using images inside this container you should use

```
$(window).load(function ()
```

instead of

```
$(function() {
```

because images are not loaded in the dom.